# NSRegularExpression string delimited by

Tags: objective-c, ios, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

I have a string for example `@"You've earned Commentator and 4 ##other$$ badges"`. I want to retreive the substring `@"other"`, which is delimited by `##` and `$$`. I made a NSRegularExpression like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"##(.*)$$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

This completely ignores `$$` and returns stuff starting with `##`. What am I doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because '$' is a special character that represents the end of the line. Try `\$\$` to escape it and tell the parser you want the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just did this: @"##(.*)\$\$" . I get a warning saying unknown escape sequence and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Oosp, I didn't try that code myself, sorry. It probably needs to be `\\$\\$` double escaped so that the final string as the parser sees it is `\$\$`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a regex in this situation, since the string bashing is so simple.  No need for the overhead of compiling the expression.

```
NSString *source = @"You've earned Commentator and 4 ##other$$ badges";
NSRange firstDelimiterRange = [source rangeOfString:@"##"];
NSRange secondDelimiterRange = [source rangeOfString:@"$$"];
NSString *result = [source substringWithRange:
  NSMakeRange(firstDelimiterRange.origin +2, 
    firstDelimiterRange.origin - secondDelimiterRange.origin)];
```

Comment: Don't overlook NSScanner.  I often fine using NSScanner created better code than using NSRange.